# Implementing HikariCP in Xpages Javabean breaking

Tags: java, sql-server, xpages, hikaricp

I am implementing A Javabean SQL connection in Xpages. I am trying to create a connection pool for this Bean implementation using HikariCP.

Here is my code.

> Datasource Class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
 
import javax.sql.DataSource;
 
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class HikariDS
{
    private static DataSource datasource;
    
     public static DataSource getDataSource(String jdbcURL, String user, String pass)
     {
         if(datasource == null)
         {
             try
             {
                 HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                 config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcURL);
                 config.setUsername(user);
                 config.setPassword(pass);
                 config.setDataSourceClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                 config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
                 config.setAutoCommit(false);
                 config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
                 config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
                 config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
                  
                 datasource = new HikariDataSource(config);
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 System.out.println(e.toString());
             }
         }
         
         return datasource;
     }
}
```

> SQL Connection bean

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.sqlPoolConnect;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class sqlConnection implements Serializable
{   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String query;
    private String retError;
    private String conString;
    
    DataSource dataSource;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement prep = null;
    
    private String USER;
    private String PASS;
    
    public sqlConnection()
    {

    }
    
    public String getConString()
    {
        return conString;
    }
    public void setConString(String cS)
    {
        this.conString = cS;
    }

    public String getUSER() 
    {
        return USER;
    }
    
    public void setUSER(String U)
    {
        this.USER = U;
    }
    
    public void setPASS(String P)
    {
        this.PASS = P;
    }

    public String getPASS() 
    {
        return PASS;
    }

    public String getQuery() 
    {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) 
    {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public void execQuery()
    {            
        con = null;
        prep = null;
        
        try
        {
            dataSource = sqlPoolConnect.getDataSource(getConString(), getUSER(), getPASS());
            con = dataSource.getConnection();

            prep = con.prepareStatement(getQuery());
            
            prep.executeQuery();
        }
        
        catch(Exception sqlex)
        {
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        finally 
        {
            try
            {
                if(prep != null)
                {
                    prep.close();
                }
                
                con.rollback();

            }
            
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> SSJS Call of Bean

```
function testInsert(inCon)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO table_name
                 (1,2,3,4,5) ";
    sqlConnection.setUSER("USER");
    sqlConnection.setPass("PASS");
    sqlConnection.setConString(inCon);
    sqlConnection.setQuery(query);
    sqlConnection.execQuery();
}
```

When the bean is invoked. IT BREAKS AT HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(); in the KikaryDS Class.

Please advise if anyone knows why it will break over there.

Edit:

I ran the code in a separate java project and received this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
    at HikariCP.getDataSource(HikariCP.java:20)
    at HikariCP.main(HikariCP.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:925)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:870)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:343)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:853)
    ... 2 more
```

> MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1588952278176
Build-Jdk: 11.0.2
Built-By: brettw
Bundle-Description: Ultimate JDBC Connection Pool
Bundle-DocURL: https://github.com/brettwooldridge
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HikariCP
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.zaxxer.HikariCP
Bundle-Vendor: Zaxxer.com
Bundle-Version: 3.4.5
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
DynamicImport-Package: *
Export-Package: com.zaxxer.hikari;version="3.4.5";uses:="com.zaxxer.hi
 kari.metrics,javax.naming,javax.naming.spi,javax.sql",com.zaxxer.hika
 ri.hibernate;version="3.4.5";uses:="com.zaxxer.hikari,org.hibernate,o
 rg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi,org.hibernate.service.spi",c
 om.zaxxer.hikari.metrics;version="3.4.5",com.zaxxer.hikari.pool;versi
 on="3.4.5";uses:="com.zaxxer.hikari,com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics,com.zax
 xer.hikari.util,javax.sql",com.zaxxer.hikari.util;version="3.4.5";use
 s:="javax.sql"
Import-Package: javax.management,javax.naming,javax.naming.spi,javax.s
 ql,com.codahale.metrics;resolution:=optional;version="[3.2,4)",com.co
 dahale.metrics.health;resolution:=optional;version="[3.2,4)",io.micro
 meter.core.instrument;resolution:=optional,org.slf4j;version="[1.6,2)
 ",org.hibernate;resolution:=optional;version="[5.2,6)",org.hibernate.
 engine.jdbc.connections.spi;resolution:=optional;version="[5.2,6)",or
 g.hibernate.service;resolution:=optional;version="[5.2,6)",org.hibern
 ate.service.spi;resolution:=optional;version="[5.2,6)",javax.sql.rows
 et,javax.sql.rowset.serial,javax.sql.rowset.spi,org.hibernate.cfg;res
 olution:=optional;version="[5.2,6)"
Multi-Release: true
Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-4.2.0.201903051501
```

I have imported HikariCP-3.4.5.jar and slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar and have ensured it is in my Java Build Path. What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or general error message? There are a couple common candidates for why something normal wouldn't work in an XPages environment, but just "it breaks" isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Incidentally, you may have better luck going with the SQL support provided via the ExtLib, which includes connection pooling and provides the `JdbcUtil` class to get `Connection` objects from a stored config.

Comment: @JesseGallagher The run is not even hitting the catch statement in the HikariDS class. It just stops running when it hits the line mentioned in the question. So there is no stack trace for me to print. Also, I have tried the ExtLib to do connection pooling but when I have over four hubdred people accessing the webpage that calls the sql statement. I am getting many connection is closed errors returned.

Comment: Check the Xpages error log at \Domino\data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT.  This is the best place to check for Java errors in XPages.  Also, in Domino Designer, check the Package Explorer view for any errors there.